# Read CSV to a class Dataflow Java from GCS

Tags: java, csv, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, google-cloud-storage

I'm a newby on Java Dataflow and I want to read a CSV file from GCS and have in output a PCollection.

How can I do it efficiently?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would have to convert that CSV file to something else. If you can share more details on what you are trying to do with that PCollection, we could provide more insight.

Here is a very generic example that might help. Suppose that you have a CSV `gs://sample-bucket-name/teams.csv`:

```
id,name,score
1,Team A,35
2,Team B,40
```

You could [create a pipeline](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/create-your-pipeline/) and a component to convert those lines to a POJO [in which Beam knows the schema](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas-for-pl-types), for example:

```java
  @DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)
  public class Team implements Serializable {
    int id;
    String name;
    int score;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) {
        return true;
      }

      return o != null
          && o instanceof Team
          && id == ((Team) o).id;
    }
  }
```

A [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) function could look like this (although you can use any tools you'd like to read and parse CSV, instead of using `String.split`):

```java
public class TeamCSVtoBeanFunction extends DoFn<String, Team> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element String line, OutputReceiver<Team> outputReceiver) {

      // ignore header or empty lines
      if (line.equals("id,name,score") || line.isEmpty()) {
        return;
      }
      String[] split = line.split(",");

      Team team = new Team();
      team.id = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
      team.name = split[1];
      team.score = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
      outputReceiver.output(team);
    }
  }
```

Finally, the pipeline, which uses [TextIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html) to read the text file into a `PCollection` of `Team`. Ideally, you would want to use other [IOs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pipeline-io) to fulfill your needs, and write your results somewhere.

```java
    PCollection<Team> teams = pipeline
        .apply("ReadCSV", TextIO.read().from("gs://sample-bucket-name/teams.csv"))
        .apply("ConvertToBean", ParDo.of(new TeamCSVtoBeanFunction()));
```

Comment: Yeah, currently we don't have a native CSV source in Beam so options mentioned here or FileIO transforms would be your best option.